# dynamically change ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object made like this:

```
var examples = {
    'example1': {
        ex1: {},
        ex2: {},
        ex3: {}
    },
    'example2': {
        ex1: {},
        ex2: {},
        ex3: {}
    }
}
```

There is a button linked to a function which fills the example1 object with values on the first click, and the example2 object on a second click.

- First click: example1 get values.
- Second click: example2 get values.

Then i loop through the object using ng-repeat, like this:

```
data-ng-repeat="example in examples.example1.ex1"
data-ng-repeat="example in examples.example1.ex2"
data-ng-repeat="example in examples.example1.ex3"
```

The problem here is, i need the ng-repeat to somehow change and loop through the example2 object aswell when the button is clicked a second time. So my question is, is there a way to change ng-repeat dynamically?

EDIT: The goal is for the first list of appear after the first click, and then for BOTH lists appear together after the second click.

I tried to make a $scope with the value 2 and put it in the ng-repeat, but that didn't work.

```
$scope.counter = 2; //in a controller
data-ng-repeat="example in examples.example(counter).ex1"
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the ng-repeat to show the values of BOTH sets of examples, or stop showing the first set and begin showing the second set?

Comment: I want em both to be shown, the first one gets looped and printed out and then i want the second object looped and printed out below the first.

Comment: Then Jannik's answer below should do the trick. If you want the second to show after a button click, have example2 as a separate variable, then do a `examples.push(example2)` on the second click.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic property name

```
$scope.prop = 'example1';
$scope.click = function (newProp) {
    $scope.prop = newProp;
    // do whatever you want here 
    // change prop to example2 or 
    // or simply toggle Boolean to change prop text
}
```

And in html use

```
ng-repeat="example in examples[prop].ex1"
```

Comment: This won't show both examples at once. The OP clarified in the comments. (I thought like you did at first.)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a solution to loop through "examples" instead, and then have a ng-repeat inside an ng-repeat?

Something like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="example in examples">
    <div data-ng-repeat="ext in example">
        {{ext.ex1}} {{ext.ex2}} {{ext.ex3}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do something like Jannik's answer in the html and this in the JS:

```
$scope.examples = {};
function example(exes) {
    this.exes = exes;
}
$scope.onClick = function(exes) {
    $scope.examples.push(new example(exes));
}
```

The exes is a list of ex1,ex2,etc. You may need a $scope.$apply() at the end of this to update the UI.

Comment: The problem is that there could be an example3, 4 ,5 etc.. they get added dynamically and theyre all getting added to the same examples object. So i need a nonstatic way of doing this. Just trying to get it to work with two objects to start with

Comment: These objects wouldn't by chance be getting added dynamically on this button click, would they? If so, the solution is very different.